# Android webview on click

Tags: javascript, android, webview, onclick

Halo guys!

My android application has a web view link a web, suppose "google.com". I want to do one thing is when user click on "search" , my app will toast "search". And when user click on "mail" will toast mail.

I know about i can add javascript into the html to handle onClick event if the website is mine. But the situation is the website is a public website. Is there any solution?

And is it also possible to get data inside the web view for my application to use?
i am studying on REST and Jsoup.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May this help you:

Buddy you cannot get click of Inner object of Webview's in android otherthan writing Onclick in **HTML code** but you can get the click for the whole webview by Implementing `onTouchListener` on your `Webview` Object and overriding your `onTouch()` method like this:

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         if (v.getId() == R.id.my_WebView && event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

                // write your code here
            }


        return false;
    }
```

Comment: so it is not albe to show search when i click on search in google.com? anyway thank you very much!! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can Implement an onClickListener via onTouchListener:

```
webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public final static int FINGER_RELEASED = 0;
        public final static int FINGER_TOUCHED = 1;
        public final static int FINGER_DRAGGING = 2;
        public final static int FINGER_UNDEFINED = 3;

        private int fingerState = FINGER_RELEASED;


        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    if (fingerState == FINGER_RELEASED) fingerState = FINGER_TOUCHED;
                    else fingerState = FINGER_UNDEFINED;
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    if(fingerState != FINGER_DRAGGING) {
                        fingerState = FINGER_RELEASED;

                        // Your onClick codes

                    }
                    else if (fingerState == FINGER_DRAGGING) fingerState = FINGER_RELEASED;
                    else fingerState = FINGER_UNDEFINED;
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    if (fingerState == FINGER_TOUCHED || fingerState == FINGER_DRAGGING) fingerState = FINGER_DRAGGING;
                    else fingerState = FINGER_UNDEFINED;
                    break;

                default:
                    fingerState = FINGER_UNDEFINED;

            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```